# Loop to pull content from parent element in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, conditional-content

I created a hierarchical custom post type called "films." It is hierarchical so it can have children elements.

I am using a conditional statement in my single-films.php to show different content for the parent page from the children pages like so:

```
<?php if( $post->post_parent != 0 ) {
    echo "Press Page";
} else {
    echo "Film Page";
} ?>
```

In the condition that the page is a child, I want to use a custom wordpress loop, that loops through it's parents content. I am guessing I will need to use a loop similar to this (for the children):

```
<?php $posts = query_posts('&post_parent=0'); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

wordpress content

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This isn't working correctly. I need it to pull any content I wish (custom field, title, featured image, etc) from it's parent. Any idea how I can modify this loop to pull content from it's parent?

Comment: Are you trying to loop through ONLY the parent, or are you trying to loop through the parent and the child?

Comment: only the parent

Comment: Avoid `query_posts`, it should *never* be used, it will only cause you pain, headaches, nausea, and horrible migraine induced vomitting

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to change the query from querying the current page to querying the parent of the current page:

```
query_posts( 'p='.$post->post_parent  );
```

That will change the `$wp_query` object to hold only the parent of the current post.

Note: this is untested.

## update

You can also do it with a custom `WP_Query` as so:

```
$args = array(
    'p' => $post->post_parent
);
$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();
    // loop stuff here
endwhile;
```

Comment: yea, this solution isnt working for me. THe logic makes sense...

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: it has some strange permalink behavior and spits out an error:  Fatal error: Cannot redeclare curpageurl() (previously declared

Comment: Try the updated method that I just posted, looks like `query_posts()` wants to be difficult.

Comment: I tried it with no luck. Thanks for your efforts though, it seems that this isn't a common problem. What is the 'p'?

Comment: the `WP_Query` representation for postid. What do you get if you `print_r($post)` and `print_r( $parent )`?

Comment: I get a SUPER long string of post data., it also screws up my breadcrumbs quite a bit, and seems to be pulling wrong data

Comment: Use that information to troubleshoot. I can only help you as much as you can help yourself.

Comment: you could also get_post() since you only seem to be after 1 post.  m0r7if3r's answer looks right to me too.  maybe you need to global $post ?  what's in the print_r($parent)?  for instance, is post_title and post_content the right pieces for your parent item?  if so, then it could be a problem w/ your loop and not the query

Comment: I found a working method, similar to yours. It is to use get post meta, like this:  <?php $cast_members = get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'cast_members', true); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Use get post meta to extract the parents custom field:

for an image:

```
<?php

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'custom-field-key', true));
echo '<img src="' . $image[0] . '" />';
?>
```

For a text custom field:

```
<?php $variable = get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'custom_field_name', true); ?>
```